# Invalid object name error for a function used in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012:

```
drop table ttt
create table ttt(id int,amt int)
insert into ttt values(1,100),(2,200),(1,200),(3,400),(1,500)

create function dbo.t1(@id int)
returns int
with returns null on null input
as
begin
declare @amt_total int
select @amt_total=sum(amt) from ttt
where id=@id
return @amt_total
end

select t.id,t.amt,f.id from ttt t cross apply dbo.t1(t.id) f
```

The code returns following error on execution:
`Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 16
Invalid object name 'dbo.t1'.`

any help?

the function,tables are all present in same schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you are using is suitable for *table-valued user-defined functions* which return a table data type instead of just a scalar value.

Try this syntax instead:

```
SELECT t.id, t.amt, f.id 
FROM ttt t 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.t1(t.id) ) f(id)
```

Comment: I doing this `select t.id as id1,t.amt as amt1,f.id as id2 from ttt t cross apply (select dbo.t1(t.id)) f` but it gives error:  `Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'f'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'id'.
`

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna Take a more careful look at my post: I am using `f(id)`, not just `f`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - Nice answer, I am still doubtful on why the OP wants to use `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @ughai I think he took up the syntax used for inline UDFs, e.g. from a site like this http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=03116fe3-d65f-41b8-9a5d-96ce4fcd9e7d&tkw=how-to-join-with-an-inline-user-defined-function

Answer (score 2):

its a scalar function. you need to call it like this

```
select t.id,t.amt,dbo.t1(t.id) id from ttt t
```

For more info about types of functions in `SQL Server`, refer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It's correct, just change `f` alias to `id` to match exactly the OP expression.